# How to create a grid view?

Tags: php, jquery, gridview

How to create a `gridview` or gallery view with **PHP and jQuery**?

Comment: Mate - you've gotta put a bit more effort into the question. see the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Your question is much too broad.

Comment: You don't even need jquery to do this

Comment: Ask yourself: How would you create a grid in HTML? (Easy hint: tables) Then ask yourself: What code must you write to generate this HTML using PHP? Then try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of [jQuery Grid Plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [another alternate link](http://www.phpgrid.org/) which help you to create grid view in PHP.